# Polyline won't show up in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm using Xcode 8.3.2 so first I import mapkit. Then I set markers to the map. Then I add the following code to add a polyline to the map but it won't show any.

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
     self.mapView.delegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let template = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        let point1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 6.9271, longitude: 79.8612);
        let point2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 9.6615, longitude: 80.0255);

            let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)
            overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(6.878069, 79.892119)
            mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
            mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 1100, 1100), animated: true)
            let pin = PinAnnotation(title: "Nimbus", subtitle: "Best", coordinate: location)
            mapView.addAnnotation(pin)



        let points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
        points = [point1, point2]

        let polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: points, count: 3)
        mapView.add(polyline)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
            let region1 = MKCoordinateRegion(center: point1, span: span)
            self.mapView.setRegion(region1, animated: true)
        })
       }
 func mapView(_ mapview: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) ->MKOverlayRenderer{
                    if let overlayGeodesic = overlay as? MKGeodesicPolyline
                    {
                        let overLayRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlayGeodesic)
                        overLayRenderer.lineWidth = 5
                        overLayRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                        return overLayRenderer

                    }
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add this line, I think you already have added but anyway

```
    self.mapView.delegate = self
```

After that you need to implement this `MKMapViewDelegate` method `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer` and return the `MKOverlayRenderer` needed for your current overlay in this case `MKPolylineRenderer` this is an important part if you don't implement this method then you never will have your polyline rendered

**implementation will be something like this**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if let overlayGeodesic = overlay as? MKGeodesicPolyline
    {
        let overLayRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlayGeodesic)
        overLayRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        overLayRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        return overLayRenderer
    }

    if let overlayTile = overlay as? MKTileOverlay{
        let overLayRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlayTile)
        return overLayRenderer
    }

   return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```

**And voila! there is your polyLine rendered**

[image]

Comment: after i add that part it asks for a "missing return in a function expected to return 'MKOverlayRenderer'"

Comment: check again my answer was updated, you only need to add `return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)` outside the if, must work now

Comment: thnx dude I'll update my question. now polyline displays but the Map won't display. can u help with that

Comment: @Saneth check your internet connection, your map should render without problems, anyway I think your question was answered already

Comment: self.mapView.delegate = self   when i add his code map won't display

Comment: the issue is for this line `mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)` comment this line to test and let me know

Comment: @Saneth check my answer again and let me know I Had added the MKTileOverlayRenderer in the method, if you had commented the line `mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)` uncomment again and test my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152696/discussion-between-saneth-and-reinier-melian).